PostgreSQL logical replication without a static IP
I have a PostgreSQL database that is running on AWS. I also have a database running locally on a Raspberry Pi, that is supposed to replicate the changes from the AWS one. I was thinking of using Postgres' logical replication feature, but I am not sure if it is doable without setting a static IP address or a DNS entry for my Raspberry Pi, which I don't want to do.
Is it doable? Is it a good idea?
I looked at AWS IoT Core, which would be AWS's solution for this problem, but I feel like it is an overkill.

Solely from the replication point of view, the subscriber IP address is of no importance to the publisher, as the connection is initiated by the subscriber.
However, from the security perspective this could be a problem, because you will have to configure the publisher server ingress (an AWS security group and the Postgres HBA rules) to allow subscriber access, which will either have to be modified each time the subscriber IP address changes, or will have to be set too permissive for comfort.

Using a VPN and allowing only the private subnet would be a solution to that issue right?
